# Bulk assignment of multiple users to an app in Okta through Postman API

Tags: rest, http-headers, postman, okta, okta-api

I am trying to add some users to an application in Okta simultaneously through Postman API i.e. bulk assignment of multiple users to an app. Assigning them at a time will save my manual labour as well as time.

For example, suppose we have been given the email IDs of 10 users who all need to be assigned to an application (let's say VEEVA). Is there any effective way of doing this through Postman API?

Comment: Do you mean the *Okta* API? Postman is just a client for making requests. And if you do mean that, have you read their API docs?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, yes I mean Okta API. I have gone through API docs shared on developer.okta.com but didn't get anything useful related to bulk assignments. Please help.